# How can I use a select box with jQuery AutoComplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Right now I have my Autocomplete widget in a text box. Ideally, it would be a Select box, but I can't figure out how to let somebody type in a select box.

So I am relegated to having a text box and a hidden box. The hidden box should get updated with the id of what displays in the text box.

I am pretty new to jQuery, at least on an in-depth level like this. Am I making this harder than I need to? I definitely need autocomplete, because there are potentially hundreds of thousands of possible values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is [a great example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox) of precisely this on the jQueryUI demo page for autocomplete. It actually uses a `select` element as the backing store.

You could easily modify this to use a remote data source. If you need the source to be remote, let me know and I can provide an example.

Comment: Watch out that that example explicitly says that "This is not a supported or even complete widget. Its purely for demoing what autocomplete can do with a bit of customization", may have some issues (and I've had some of those with it :( )

Answer (score 20):

You should look into the jQuery plugin called [`chosen`](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/).
I think it's the best jQuery plugin written in the past year (or more).

> Chosen is a JavaScript plugin that makes long, unwieldy select boxes much more user-friendly. It is currently available in both jQuery and Prototype flavors.

Comment: @user3227070 - at the time, this was the best. But `select2` has since superseded it.

Answer (score 19):

There is a very good alternative for "chosen" - ["Select2" (jQuery only)](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/index.html).

> **"Select2" use cases**
>
> - Enhancing native selects with search.
> - Enhancing native selects with a better multi-select interface.
> - Loading data from JavaScript: easily load items via ajax and have them searchable.
> - Nesting optgroups: native selects only support one level of nested. Select2 does not have this restriction.
> - Tagging: ability to add new items on the fly.
> - Working with large, remote datasets: ability to partially load a dataset based on the search term.
> - Paging of large datasets: easy support for loading more pages when the results are scrolled to the end.
> - Templating: support for custom rendering of results and selections.